# Cannot hide all extensions using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I can't get my htaccess file to hide all file extensions (html and php in my case).

If I type in 'example.com/home.html',

I want 'example.com/home' shown in the address bar.

Is this possible to do with htaccess without changing my html code to 'href="/home" '?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched some more and found that you already provided a solution for this in another post.

```
# browser requests html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a html file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Is this solution working for you to hide `.php` extensions also?

Comment: Just html. I imagine if you replace all the html's in the code to the extension you want hidden that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(.+)\.html(\?\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.

Comment: No good. Same result as the other codes i've found. It allows the files tp run without the extension but it still shows in the address bar.